# Stanford 3.7 models on Maven?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am using Stanford 3.7 for NER/RegexNER. I have the following Maven dependencies in my pom:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <classifier>models</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

And I am using the Stanford CoreNLP API, [following the documentation](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/api.html):

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("regexner.mapping", "my_file_name");
props.put("regexner.ignorecase", "true");
props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, ner, regexner");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

Annotation document = new Annotation(text);
pipeline.annotate(document);
```

However, I still get the RuntimeException error:

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to open "edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger" as class path, filename or URL
```

Does anyone know how to use the API with the models from version 3.7? Any advice welcome.

Answer (score 1):

That file is in the stanford-corenlp-3.7.0-models.jar so it might be that when you are running your application somehow that jar is not in the CLASSPATH.  How are you running this Java code?

Comment: Thanks for the response, the classpath was definitely the problem. I had an earlier version without the models file in my classpath that the code was calling, so stupid! Thanks again.